# What should we do when firebase is connected in the app but it doesn't show correct result?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have an app in android studio and I use firebase authentication in first page of my app. I have used google account authentication. Sometimes I want to enter the app but I can't. when I see the firebase settings in my app it is correctly connected. what should I do? Should I reinstall my app in AVD? Or should I clean and rebuild my project in android studio? Or should I check internet connection?

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just changed the tags.  But I will say that your question is not very well formed for Stack Overflow.  I suggest reading this in order to clarify your question and explain better what you're observing: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you @Doug Stevenson, but almost everyday I have problem when I want to connect to firebase for first time. Because in Iran, firebase is filtered and I should turn on VPN to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I try different ways for solving the problem, I think my answer is that I should wait for several minutes to use firebase authentication. My app is connected to firebase but it takes several minutes for its authentication to work correctly. Surely the time that I should wait is related to my internet. The better internet connection, the faster authentication.